# Altium paste component at a new pattern shape( like circular or ...)

Tags: altium, smart, paste

I need to past the component in PCB part automatically in one new pattern shape,So is there any why to draw pattern and paste component in that pattern automatically by Altium ( similar to align option but in new pattern type)?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I know that a circular shape is possible.  Circular and linear are the only options, although with clever use of copying linear you could easily make a grid or array, and later manually remove some if needed.

To do circular, copy the object you'd like to paste in a circular pattern.

Edit --> Paste Special

For example, lets paste a via into a circle every 45 degrees.  Select options as shown:

[image]

You'll see dialogue prompts at the bottom of the window.  First, click to select the location of the center point.  Then click where you want the first object (I selected the centerpoint of my original)... and

Voila!

[image]

You may need to delete an extra one that pasted over your original, or any other extras depending on if you calculated correctly how many you need.  Sometimes if I'm lazy I'll just select the angle, set the item count high, then delete the extras.  If I don't feel like thinking.  :-)

Hope that helped, please consider selecting answer if it did.