# Altium: Place components along circular path

Tags: altium

There are basically two pairs of 10 LEDs, each in 0603 package. I need to place both of them in a circular path at 36 degree apart. I need to try a few different circle radius before I finally how I want the end product to be.

In Eagle PCB, I could just run a ULP script that would place the parts. How do I place parts along a circle or any other uniform path (that can be defined using formula) in the Altium designer PCB editor?

Comment: Perhaps this will [answer your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282415/altium-paste-component-at-a-new-pattern-shape-like-circular-or).

Comment: I am using Altium 22.2.1. I am trying to put components that were in schematic, into circular pattern in the PCB view. I do not see why that should require copy paste since paste creates new components.

Comment: Agreed, previous comment not helpful. See answer below.

Comment: Altium  has scripting, I don't get the impression it is all that easy to do compared to just placing 10 LEDs on a snap grid (or even just typing in the coordinates on older versions). Maybe if you had 200.

Comment: What does Altium use internally, VBA? JavaScript? Python? Something Altium specific? I just calculated the values in Excel and then input them into the Altium designer. I am 50% done so far after all this time.

Comment: @quantum231 If memory serves, VBA and Delphi. Might have changed recently though. I've only used scripts rather than written them.

Comment: Wow, I wonder who thought of using delphi. Anyway, hopefully they will learn common sense and move to Python in 50 years time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to place a local polar grid. If the "Comp" check box is checked, parts will automatically rotate when placed on the polar grid. This requires manual placement of the parts.

[image]

Comment: I did not know Altium could have polar grid as well. I created an excel spreadsheet and have been using that to calculate XY coordinates for the components and their silk screen, about 25% done so far. Lets see what this polar coordinate system can do.

Comment: I am getting option to add horizontal, vertical, +45 or -45 deg guide and add snap point. I do not see option Comp.

Comment: @quantum231 The image is divided in to 3 sections. Left is the pcb layout screen, middle is the polar settings dialog to configure the local grid, right is the Properties tab (click in a clear area of the layout screen). Click on Add to create a new local grid and select Add Polar Grid. Double-click on the newly created grid in the Properties tab (left red arrow is pointing to the line to double-click on). Enable snapping parts to the polar grid by checking the box the right arrow is pointing to.

Comment: I don't know why it did not work yesterday. However, I have been able to add the polar grid and by enabling comp, the components snap to it and rotate as they should (automatically) as well.